# Is there something like xinput but for output instead

Tags: linux, xserver

I just found out that you can use `xinput` to sniff key strokes across apps running on `X`

Is there something similar but to output data to whatever app has the focus now?

I would like to implement something like an autocomplete or smart suggestion program that listens for your keystrokes across applications and makes smart suggestion

e.g listen to whatever happens on the browser then if you switch to terminal or your text editor you can reuse some of that data.

Comment: Might make more sense to implement this as an LD_PRELOAD library, but even that's a hack. Even better would be to implement it inside Qt or Gtk or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send keyboard events to an X application using [XSendEvent](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man3/XDisplayMotionBufferSize.3.xhtml) or the [XTEST extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libXtst/xtestlib.html). XTEST is significantly more powerful, but in many cases it has to be manually enabled in the X server configuration. See also [this](http://homepage3.nifty.com/tsato/xvkbd/events.html) and [this](http://hewner.com/2006/07/16/xtestfakekeyevent-and-xsendevent-examples/) for more information and some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

[uinput](http://svn.navi.cx/misc/trunk/inputpipe/uinput/uinput.txt)

Comment: uinput has the disadvantage of being rather indiscriminate with regard to where it sends its events - it would merely simulate an additional keyboard. It may also require root privileges to access its device node.